# How to map a word to sentences the word is used in in a database?

Tags: database-design

We are trying to build a website for our school project. The site will be about a user entering a word and getting the sentences the word is used in and their translations. How can an effective database be designed to map a word to sentences the word is used in? We can simply create a word-to-sentence ID's table, but it is not better than writing everything into a file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relational database for this is going into *"when all you have is a hammer"* territory.  Searching for strings in text is a special case that many database engines have special tools for.

Nevertheless, if you want to use RDBMS then your idea of keeping a table full of sentences and a table full of words with an intersection table linking the two makes sense from a couple of perspectives.  Since you're also looking at translations you want a word table to link words in different languages.  Also, if your word-to-sentence table contains a sequence number you can use that to find sentences where two words are used near (within a given distance of) each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like Apache Solr for this kind of task. These things are called text search engines and they are specifically designed to do this. They can even find words that have prefix or suffixes, according to the specific language's rules, or can match words with the same meaning etc (for example searching for "tool" and finding sentences containing "device").